# Openlayers feature not drawn without map refreshing

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I am trying to draw the icon of the feature (defined as OpenLayers.Feature.Vector) after clicking on it (different than the original one, at the same point). The process of clicking works really good, however I want to change the graphic of clicked feature and I have problems with that.

What am I doing?

At first I declare both layers (one for the original, selectable feature and then for the one that should be drawn after the first one is selected) and add it to the map:

```
var firstLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector('Layer1');
map.addLayer(firstLayer);
var selectedLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector('Selected');
map.addLayer(selectedLayer);
```

The layers are clickable, proper handlers are attatched to them. What is more, I create styles for features that could be drawn on both layers:

```
 // Styling feature of type1 for Layer1
 type1Marker = openLayers.Util.applyDefaults(type1Marker, openLayers.Feature.Vector.style['default']);
 type1Marker.externalGraphic = "somefile.svg";
 type1Marker.pointRadius = iconsRadius;
 type1Marker.fillOpacity = 1;

 // Styling feature of type1 for Selected layer
 type1MarkerSelected= openLayers.Util.applyDefaults(type1MarkerSelected, openLayers.Feature.Vector.style['default']);
 eventObdConnectionLostIconSelectedStyle.externalGraphic ="somefile_selected.svg";
 type1MarkerSelected.pointRadius = iconsRadius;
 type1MarkerSelected.fillOpacity = 1;

 // Styling feature of type2 for Layer1
 type2Marker = openLayers.Util.applyDefaults(type2Marker, openLayers.Feature.Vector.style['default']);
 type2Marker.externalGraphic = "somefile2.svg";
 type2Marker.pointRadius = iconsRadius;
 type2Marker.fillOpacity = 1;

 // Styling feature of type2 for Selected layer
 type2MarkerSelected= openLayers.Util.applyDefaults(type2MarkerSelected, openLayers.Feature.Vector.style['default']);
 type2MarkerSelected.externalGraphic = "somefile2_selected.svg";
 type2MarkerSelected.pointRadius = iconsRadius;
 type2MarkerSelected.fillOpacity = 1;
```

Then some features for Layer1 are created at different points. I store those features in an array of features expanded by some additional data that I use later to distinguish the type of the marker that I want to use and I store the position of the marker on the map.  And now there goes some logic that is executted after clicking on any feature :

```
var size = new OpenLayers.Size(30, 30);
var offset = new OpenLayers.Pixel(-(size.w / 2), -size.h);
var icon = new OpenLayers.Icon('http://www.openlayers.org/dev/img/marker.png', size, offset);
var marker = new OpenLayers.Feature.Vector(closestPoint, icon);
var markerSel = new OpenLayers.Feature.Vector(closestPoint.event.point, icon);
switch (closestPoint.type) {
    case "type1":
        markerSel.style = type1MarkerSelected;
        break;
    case "type2":
        markerSel.style = type2MarkerSelected;
        break;
}

var selectedLayer = map.getLayersByName('Selected')[0];
if (selectedLayer.features.length != 0)
   selectedLayer.removeAllFeatures();
selectedLayer.addFeatures(markerSel);
selectedLayer.redraw({ force: true });
```

What is going on is really weird for me, i.e.: after clicking on the marker from Layer1 nothing happens, then if I scroll out the map it disappears and finally when I scroll more, the marker is displayed with the style I wanted (that is selected one). Especially the disappearing of the feature from Layer1 is something that I do not get at all - why it disappears while no operations on that layer are performed? I would like to stack the new icon above the one from Layer1 (zOrdering of the map is set to true and the Layer1 is defined before the Selected layer).

Does anybody know what could cause the problem? I have spent several hours on trying to fix it but now I'm out of ideas. Thank you in advance!

Comment: It is likely to be some bizarre interaction of things, as layer.redraw() should be enough. Is there any way you could post a minimal working example demonstrating the problem in jsFiddle?

Comment: You already know that OL supports select highlightning out of the box? http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.13.1/examples/highlight-feature.html